# How to handle data loading with asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am loading data for a log. It runs smoothly. However, I added a gone indeterminate progress bar below toolbar which always shows every time Asynctask is called.

1. Is it possible to avoid showing this when data was loaded so fast?
2. Is `thread.sleep` recommended in this?
3. Or a progressbar is not needed even loading 500 and above records?

Here's my code:

```
public void refreshList(String status) {
    String id = String.valueOf(getArguments().getInt("ID"));

    String paramsValue[] = new String[2];
    paramsValue[0] = id;
    paramsValue[1] = status;
    new LogsTask(this).execute(paramsValue);

}

private static class LogsTask extends AsyncTask<String[], Integer, LinkedHashMap<Integer, ValuesExtension>> {
    String paramsValue[];

    LogsFragment logsFragment;
    WeakReference<LogsFragment> fragmentWeakReference;

    LogsTask(LogsFragment logsFragment) {
        fragmentWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(logsFragment);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        logsFragment = fragmentWeakReference.get();
        logsFragment.pbLogs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    
    }

    @Override
    protected LinkedHashMap<Integer, ValuesExtension> doInBackground(String[]... params) {
        Cursor dbReader = null;

        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(logsFragment.getContext());
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, ValuesExtension> logsMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        try {              
            dbHelper.open();

            if (dbReader.getCount() > 0) {
                while (dbReader.moveToNext()) {
                    try {
                        /* LOADING OF DATA */
                        logsMap.put("values", value);

                        Thread.sleep(250); // is this important when loading data?
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (dbReader != null) {
                dbReader.close();
            }
            dbHelper.close();
        }
        return logsMap;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(LinkedHashMap<Integer, ValuesExtension> logsMap) {           
        logsFragment.pbLogs.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (logsMap != null) {
            logsFragment.refreshLog();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like [`ContentLoadingProgressBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ContentLoadingProgressBar.html) might be what you want.

Comment: @MikeM. Seems enough for what I need but regarding to my number 2 question, what is your opinion?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `ContentLoadingProgressBar` obviates the need for you to do any timing or delays yourself.

Comment: Oh, wait, do you mean the `sleep()` you have in the `while` loop? No, you don't need that.

Comment: @MikeM. ok, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As a work around, you can delay the start of progress bar for 300 milliseconds depending on how fast your data is loading

```
private boolean completed = false;
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        logsFragment = fragmentWeakReference.get();
        //below code won't display progress if your task completes within 300 ms and longer tasks it will be shown after 300 ms
        logsFragment.pbLogs.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
          @Override
          public void run(){
               if(!completed)
               logsFragment.pbLogs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
         }, 300);  
    }

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(LinkedHashMap<Integer, ValuesExtension> logsMap) {      
        completed = true;     
        logsFragment.pbLogs.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (logsMap != null) {
            logsFragment.refreshLog();
        }

    }
```

Comment: as a work around, this also helps but I'll consider `ContentLoadingProgressBar`. Thanks anyway.